# NCron .NET Scheduling Issue

Tags: c#-4.0, ncron

I'm trying to use NCron scheduling framework but it does not get past the Bootsrap. Shoult NCron load this ServiceSetup method dynamically? I suspect that I am simply not using the correctly but I am following the limited examples o the website.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Bootstrap.Init(args, ServiceSetup);
    }
    static void ServiceSetup(SchedulingService service)
    {
        service.At("0 0/5 * * * ?").Run<MyJob>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A single expression is composed of 5 space-delimited fields:
MINUTES HOURS DAYS MONTHS DAYS-OF-WEEK

http://code.google.com/p/ncrontab/wiki/CrontabExpression